# Android: ExoPlayer: create MediaSource from DefaultHttpDataSource

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use ExoPlayer for playback of videos from url in my app and need to set an authorization header for each video. DefaultHttpDataSource can be used for that. For example,

```
DefaultHttpDataSource source = new DefaultHttpDataSource(Util.getUserAgent(mContext, "appAgent"), null);
            source.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authToken);
```

MediaSource is needed to prepare the player. The question is how to create a MediaSource based on DefaultHttpDataSource? 
Both of the constructors of ExtractorMediaSource require DataSource.Factory, not DataSource.

Answer (score 3):

This returns a Datasource.Factory object:

`return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, null, new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(mContext, "appAgent"), null));`